# How to override abstract trait type in subclasses

Tags: scala, inheritance, traits, abstract-type

I would like to define a trait with a method that returns a generic type value and
then define a class hierarchy where a parent class defines a specific generic type value and the subclass defines a different one, like so:

```
trait Thingy {
  type T
  def doIt(): T
}

class A extends Thingy {
  override type T = Array[Int]
  override def doIt(): T = {
    Array[Int](1, 2, 3)
  }
}

class B extends A {
  override type T = Array[String]
  def doIt(): T = {
    Array[String]("stringy")
  }
}

val aa = new A()
println(aa.doIt().length)

val bb = new B()
println(bb.doIt()(0))
```

This generates compile errors

```
ScalaFiddle.scala:16: error: overriding type T in class A, which equals scala.this.Array[scala.this.Int];
 type T has incompatible type;
 found   : B.this.T
    (which expands to)  scala.this.Array[String]
 required: A.this.T
    (which expands to)  scala.this.Array[scala.this.Int]
    override type T = Array[String]
                  ^
ScalaFiddle.scala:17: error: overriding method doIt in class A of type ()B.this.T;
 method doIt needs `override' modifier;
 found   : ()B.this.T
    (which expands to)  ()scala.this.Array[String]
 required: ()A.this.T
    (which expands to)  ()scala.this.Array[scala.this.Int]
    def doIt(): T = {
        ^
```

I have tried parameterized types, abstract classes, and traits but I can't seem to get it right.
Can someone explain if there is a way to do it?

**Adding use case to answer Luis Miguel Mejía Suárez**

I'm simply trying to use inheritance to inherit common methods while maintaining 2 different data structures to represent the internal state of each class.
Say the parent class is a Grid that represents its internal data structure with a 2D Array of Cells of known dimensions

```
class Grid(var rows, var columns) {
  protected var _grid: Array[Array[Cell]] = makeGrid()
  def makeGrid(): Array[Array[Cell]] = {
    var g = Array.ofDim[Cell](rows, columns)
    // populate g
    g
  }
}
```

and I have a subclass that needs to represent the grid with a mutable ArrayBuffer:

```
class OtherGrid(var rows) extends Grid(rows, 1) {
  protected var _grid: ArrayBuffer[ArrayBuffer[Cell]] = makeGrid()
  override def makeGrid(): ArrayBuffer[ArrayBuffer[Cell]] = {
    // initialize and populate the grid
  }
}
```

Is this the wrong way to go about things in a functional programming language?

Comment: What you want to do is not possible in any language that supports basic subtyping. You are trying to break the Liskov Substitution Principle. Any subclass of `A` must respect its contract. Why do you want to do this? What is your use case?

Comment: https://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/11369

Comment: @simianarmy sorry it seems your message was not complete.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez sorry - I edited my answer with a use case

Comment: Perhaps Family Polymorphism is what I could use http://web.archive.org/web/20150827115928/http://www.familie-kneissl.org/Members/martin/blog/family-polymorphism-in-scala

Comment: This has nothing to do with functional programming, in fact, subtyping is one of the core idea behind pop languages _(however your code is also by far not functional, but whatever)_. I really do not see why `makeGrid` is not in the companion object and why it is public. Finally, are you sure your other grid should extend grid? Maybe you should create a supper trait for both which defines the contract all girds should provide and each implementation is separated from the others.

Comment: Thanks @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez, I created a Grid trait with abstract defs for the common functions that all the grid classes could extend.